# How to use event.stopPropagation() in delegate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-bubbling

My Code is like following in html:

```
<li class="arrow">    
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anchor">remove</a> 
    </div>                      
</li>
```

And I bind my elements using deligate() jquery method (because elements appear dynamically)

```
$obj.delegate(".arrow", "click", function() {
    alert("clicked on arrow");
});

$obj.delegate(".anchor", "click", function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     alert("anchor clicked");
});
```

My Problem is, when I click on ".anchor" then both events occurs. can anyone tell me how to use event.stopPropagation() in this context? I tried like the above but not working. Is there any other way to do this?

**EDIT:** I tried with calling event.isPropagationStopped(), and it returns true. but still both events called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522941/event-propagation-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is limitations when `delegate` or `live` is used and `stopPropagation`.

You return `false` in you handler to prevent both `eventPropagation` and `default`

Try

```
$obj.delegate(".anchor", "click", function(event) {
     alert("anchor clicked");
     return false;
});
```

Comment: wow, a lot has happened in the 4 minutes it took to write my answer :) - is there any reason you have left .stopPropagation() in the code? I don't believe it does anything in this context

Comment: No reason. I just copied the part. I left it there by mistake.

Comment: To make it clearer to the next person who comes along, I've removed stopPropagation() from the answer (if my edit goes through).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that with `.delegate` and `.live` you need to `return false`. I believe this is because of how the event is attached - not to the element but to it's ancestor.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/G3k8Z/