# What does propagateEvents="true" perform?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have in my project(written by others) handlebars template the following code snippet

```
{{view view.textfield propagateEvents="true"}}
```

I want to know what `propagateEvents="true"` does ?...Thanks

Comment: could you add a link to the documentation where you've read this? Shouldn't it be `Ember.TextField` I can find no reference in ember to `propagateEvents` properties.

Comment: @albertjan try the handlebars docu?

Comment: Yes. there isn't event _one_ javascript property or function called that on gh [see](https://github.com/search?q=propagateEvents&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Everything&language=JavaScript)

Comment: `view.textfield` is probably something written by the others so you should be able to see in code what it does. if you paste it here we can look for it aswel :)

Comment: Basically, I have a view with a "textfield" property which extends Ember.TextField, it has some events such as "focusout" etc....I'm calling that textfield in my handlebars using "view.textfield". I understood all these steps except for the "propagateEvents"...Is propagateEvents related to JavaScript ?

Comment: Have a look at what event propagation does/is: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522941/event-propagation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember.Button (which I believe is being deprecated) has a propagateEvents property, but not Ember.TextField.

From the handlebars action helper documentation:

#### Event Propagation

> Events triggered through the action helper will automatically have
>       `.preventDefault()` called on them. You do not need to do so in your event
>       handlers. To stop propagation of the event, simply return `false` from your
>       handler.
>
> If you need the default handler to trigger you should either register your
>       own event handler, or use event methods on your view class.