# This Show/Hide function doesn't work when click on an unordered (ul) list

Tags: jquery, html-lists, show-hide

I am styling a few MultiSelect elements with unordered (`<ul>`) HTML lists and this function is meant to hide the element when a user clicks anywhere on the document other than 'dropdown_box' or 'dropdown_container'.

The function isn't working for anything within the `<ul>`tags, and it's hiding the element as soon as soon as a list item is clicked.  I've tried specifying both the id of the `<div>` as well as the `<ul>` and it still closes as soon as it's clicked.

**UPDATE -** I created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/ezxSF/16/

There is a separate mouseleave function which closes the element for most uses, but I need to add this functionality in order to close the element if the user clicks to open it but doesn't mouse over any of the 'UL Element' items.

JS

```
$('html').click(function (e) {           
    if (e.target.id == 'dropdown_box' || e.target.id == 'dropdown_container') {
        $("#select_colors").show();
    } else {
        $("#select_colors").hide();
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="dropdown_box">Select</div>
<div id="dropdown_container"> 
    <ul id="select_colors"> 
        <!-- Several List Item Elements --> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not enough information. Please recreate the problem on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Your click event is bubbling up and you're catching it too late.

Comment: @j08691 - Would you mind elaborating on that and showing me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this a different way. Attach a global click handler to "body" that hides the div, and attach a click handler to your dropdown_box and dropdown_container that *stops the propagation* of the event (by returning false and calling e.stopPropagation). This way the body event handler will never see the event.

```
$('html').click(function () {$('#select_colors').hide(); });
$('#dropdown_box, #dropdown_container').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

**UPDATE**
changed body to html, and hid the "select_colors" instead of the dropdown_container.

http://jsfiddle.net/KJmtG/

Some references:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

[Event propagation in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522941/event-propagation-in-javascript)

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but something's still not right because the element no longer closes when I click elsewhere on the page.  I created a jsfiddle with my original code, if you wouldn't mind taking another look at it http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/ezxSF/16/

Comment: that should do it for you. See the jsfiddle I created

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('html').click(function () {
    $("#select_colors").hide();
});
$('#dropdown_box, #dropdown_container').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#select_colors").show();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ezxSF/17/)**

Clicking on the html will hide the list, while clicking on #dropdown_box or #dropdown_container will show it and stop the event bubbling.

Comment: It's exactly what I needed, but @JaredForsyth beat you to it :-) I'm feeling the love here tonight, and wish I could accept both answers :-)