# Bug : Bootstrap Modal Box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3, I created a NavBar containing a link to launch a bootstrap modalbox.

After seconds, the modalbox freezes!! When I click outside it, it disappears and all the website layout bugs (Background color changes, menu position ... ) .. then I can't open it any more! Should refresh the page ...

I've noted that the ModalBox adds "modal-open" class to `<body>` but while closing, the class is still here ...

LINK : www.tafraout.net
Click on : "Espace Membre" to launch ModalBox

BUG SCREENSHOT :  http://d.pr/i/6Tpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to open the modal directly from a javascript console, for example by evaluating `$( "#LoginModal" ).modal( "toggle" );`, it works great. That means that you are not opening it the right way ; in fact, it is the `href` attribute that is missing the thing.

When you click on your link, Bootstrap will intercept the event and toggle the modal dialog ; **however**, Javascript is doing *event propagation* (see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522941/event-propagation-in-javascript) for more information), and that means that your link is then executed normally. Because you put an absolute URL in it, it will try to send you to an new page.

Two ways to solve it : either you put `#` as the link target, but you will still have some moving in your window because the browser will focus the top of the page. In your case, that won't do any bad, but it can lead to some weird behaviors if you don't know this trick.

The second solution is to attach an event to the link, and toggle the modal manually ; for example with jQuery :

```
$( "#yourLink" ).on( "click", function() {
    $( "#LoginModal" ).modal( "toggle" ); // Toggle the modal
    return false;
});
```

`return: false;` will stop the event propagation, and so your link is not followed (nothing will change in your page) ; if you don't want to use the `return` value, you can simply call `stopPropagation()` on the event object (don't forget to include it in your function :

```
$( "#yourLink" ).on( "click", function( e ) {
    $( "#LoginModal" ).modal( "toggle" ); // Toggle the modal
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys !

It's working, i've deleted the href attribute !

I will try the Js solution too the enhance the experience.

Thanks again, 
Voted

Answer (score 1):

Try updating this in your `Se Connecter`

```
<a data-target="#LoginModal" data-toggle="modal" href="http://www.tafraout.net/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>
Se Connecter
</a>
```

to

```
<a data-target="#LoginModal" data-toggle="modal" > <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>
Se Connecter
</a>
```

without `href` attribute that should work